# Is it possible to remove city labels from a JxMaps map implementation?

Tags: java, jxmaps

Im currently working on a student project in Java with the end goal of displaying a map for a simple game. To do this Im using the JxMaps API with some google map APIs to be able to display a map in a Java swing application.

I have been looking into the functionality of the JxMaps API and am looking for a way to remove labels from the map(City and country labels). Do you know if this is possible? or if not, is there a workaround to solve this?

This is the documentation I've been looking into: https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxmaps/docs/index.html?help-doc.html

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, could you provide some code?

Comment: No I have not tried any coding with this particular problem yet, I have implemented JxMaps and it works perfectly, but since I dont have any experience using it yet, i dont really know where to start. So cant really provide any relevant code to this problem.